# Android: ConstraintLayout height is bigger than emulator screen's height

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a problem with ConstraintLayout height in any AndroidStudio emulator. When I run the app in several devices, I am seeing well all the layout rendering. But, when I run the app in the emulator, the bottom menu is out of range.

My **activity_main.xml** has a ConstraintLayout with a WebView and a BottomNavigationView. This is my template:

[template code and design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkZqi.jpg)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_action_bar"
        app:elevation="16dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/color_iconos_bottom_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_webview" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I run my app in the emulator, the menu is out of the screen. I can see the top part of the menu, but the icons are below the screen limit. When I do a click in that small region of the menu, I can navigate. So, in conclusion, the menu is there, but out of the limits.

[emulator rendering image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN5Kh.jpg)

When I run the app in the device, I can see the menu perfectly fitted. I downloaded the same model and SDK version emulator than the devices that I have, but I am still seeing it wrong.

So, the problem is that the ConstraintLayout height is bigger than the emulator screen's height. Can you give me any solution to this problem?

Comment: why do you have `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_webview"` ? why isn't `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` enough ?

Comment: `match_parent` is discouraged for direct children of _ConstraintLayout_. You have `match_parent` for widths and you should use `0dp` and constrain the start and end to the parent. Make this change and you may see a better result. Even if it doesn't change anything, you should still make the change.

Comment: Hi @a_local_nobody. I removed that property, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have conflict constraints, you link the `WebView` bottom to top of `Navigation` and top of Navigation to bottom of `WebView`.

Remove the link on `Navigation` to bottom of `WebView`.

Comment: Hi @Maksim Novikov. I removed the property, but nothing changed. I removed also the top constraint of WebView, and even with no height, the Navigation is below the screen. I think that the problem is the height of the ConstraintLayout, because the bottom constraint of the Navigation is the bottom of the ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Yes you need to remove the "app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_webview"" line from Navigation

Answer (score 0):

I added the property `android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"` to the `BottomNavigationView` element, and now the menu appears in the emulator. But in the device there is a black range below the menu. It seems that the ConstraintLayout's height is 45dp's bigger than the emulator screen height.